# How to delete Topic 0 in a Moodle Course

Tags: moodle

So we are running a Moodle 3.7 system. Is it not possible to delete the Topic 0 section?
The gear icon doesnt show the delete option like it does for other sections. I have searched in the forums, before posting and came across this tracker issue: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-60241?attachmentViewMode=list

Here they manually chnange the visibility in the database. This doesnt work for me. SInce students can still view the section.
Please help

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at different formats? If you edit a course, scroll down to "Course Format" - there are different course formats available. There are additional formats here : https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=type:format

Comment: We cant change the course format. Our entire organisation follows the topic format and hence we have to abide by it

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to delete section 0 in moodle if you're using the topics format. In fact even i you somehow managed to delete section 0 in the database the topic format code would catch this and reinsert section 0

Comment: From user perspective a big flaw in interface design resp. creating a lot of confusion.